# npm start failed _this.compiler.applyPluginsAsync is not a function

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, npm-start

please help me to understand what is the problem

when I start **npm start** I have a error

**_this.compiler.applyPluginsAsync is not a function**

npm version is 6.4.1
node version is v 10.13.0

my **package.json** file

```
"devDependencies": {
"@types/enzyme": "^3.1.15",
"@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.3",
"@types/jest": "^23.3.9",
"@types/node": "^10.12.9",
"@types/react": "^16.7.6",
"@types/react-dom": "^16.0.9",
"@types/react-intl": "^2.3.12",
"@types/react-redux": "^6.0.9",
"@types/react-router": "^4.4.1",
"@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
"@types/react-select": "^2.0.7",
"@types/react-table": "^6.7.16",
"@types/reactstrap": "^6.4.2",
"@types/redux": "^3.6.0",
"autoprefixer": "7.1.6",
"babel-jest": "^22.1.0",
"babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
"babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.1",
"case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
"chalk": "1.1.3",
"css-loader": "0.28.7",
"enzyme": "^3.7.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.0",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
"file-loader": "0.11.2",
"fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^0.2.10",
"fs-extra": "3.0.1",
"html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
"json-server": "^0.14.0",
"node-sass": "^4.9.3",
"postcss-loader": "2.0.8",
"react-dev-utils": "^5.0.3",
"react-dropzone": "^5.1.1",
"redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.5",
"resolve": "1.6.0",
"sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
"source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
"style-loader": "0.19.0",
"sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
"ts-jest": "22.0.1",
"ts-loader": "^2.3.7",
"tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0",
"tslint": "^5.7.0",
"tslint-config-prettier": "^1.16.0",
"tslint-react": "^3.2.0",
"typescript": "^3.1.6",
"uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.3.0",
"url-loader": "0.6.2",
"webpack": "^4.26.0",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10",
"webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.3.2"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official repo of [fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/Realytics/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin), this was reported in [this issue](https://github.com/Realytics/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin/issues/154) and fixed in version 0.6.1. Update that package and try again to see if it happens.